# Where to log error in go

Tags: logging, go, error-handling, error-logging

Perhaps this is an opinion or maybe it's actually a best practice, but I want to do it correctly.

Consider the following code:

```
func main() {
    if err := doSomething(); err != nil {
        // log here and exit?
    }
}

func doSomething() {
    f, err := os.Open("filename.ext")
    if err != nil {
        // log here and return the error/exit?
    }
}
```

I am interested to know where the error should be logged and where the program should be exited (assuming recovery is impossible). Some possibilities include: logging and exiting in the callee; logging in the callee, returning the error, and exiting in the caller; logging in the callee, returning the error, logging in the caller, and exiting. There seem to be benefits to all of these approaches. The second approach, for instance, allows a fine grained error message but still passes the error on to the caller. However, it will result in two log messages.

Thanks!

Comment: put it in a logfile or print it

Comment: https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully gives some pretty good guidance on error handling in go.

Comment: @captncraig That was a useful article. Looks like using `errors.Wrap` can give some context to an error when it is returned. I like that.

Answer (score 21):

This is an interesting topic, and really boils down to a lot of opinion, so this may get closed. There are a few guidelines I try to follow:

1. Only "handle" an error once. Logging counts as handling. If you do not know what action needs to be taken, just pass it up. You definitely don't want errors to be logged multiple times per occurrence.
2. If your caller is likely to change their behavior because of the error, you should return it. If you can still do your "job" despite the error, maybe you should log it and continue.
3. Sometimes it helps to add context to where the error initially entered your system (so the log line can include where the error came from, not just where it finally got logged). Something like https://github.com/pkg/errors can be useful for this.

Comment: To further add to this, as a rule, don't use `os.Exit()` except in your `main()` function.  Primary reason is, unlike `panic()`, `os.Exit()` cannot be caught, and `main()` really should have the authority on when the process terminates and how.  As a corollary, `os.Exit()` and by extension, `log.Fatal()` (which calls `os.Exit()`) should **_absolutely never_** be used in libraries intended to be imported by others (I see this _ALL_ the time, and it's _terrible_ practice).  If it's fatal (in an importable package), `panic()`, don't `os.Exit()` or `log.Fatal()`.

Answer (score 2):

From unit-tests standpoint, it's better to return error. If you return error for a `fn()`, it's easier to unit-test it.

For example,

```
// p.go
func fn() error {
    ...
}

// p_test.go
func TestFn(t *testing.T) {
    // returning error makes easier to test fn() here.
    if err := fn(); err != nil {
        t.Error("fn(): got:%v, want:nil", err)
    }
}
```

If `fn()` directly logged error and exited, it would be impossible to unit-test it.